# Use the http response from an azure function

Tags: azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I am trying to create a pipeline, which starts off with an Azure function, the azure functions takes some parameters, and makes another request to another service, to get some data. The Azure Function then returns a json string.

```
{
   "Response: {"name": "KarlTanner"}
}
```

When I debug the pipeline, I can see this comes out as the output from the Azure Function.

My question is, how can I use this output, for the next logically step? Would I be able to create a Data Flow? If the json string is suppose to hold alot of data, would it be preferable, for the Azure Function, to save do transformations(python) and save it to the destination. Instead of doing Data Factory transformations.

Comment: Do you have any specific scenario I could show you as an example for its usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the Json result as string to a variable.

```
@activity('Azure Function1').output.Response
```

[image]

Or if you want to **input this into DataFlow**, create a **parameter** in the dataflow and you can pass the result into the parameter to be used in dataflow.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot for your help :)

Comment: my pleasure... 